# How to HTTP POST to an API on another PC's IIS

Tags: asp.net, http, post, iis, networking

I have an extremely basic API set up on my IIS.  I'm doing nothing with the code yet:

```
public class RESTAPIController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/RESTAPI
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET: api/RESTAPI/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST: api/RESTAPI
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT: api/RESTAPI/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE: api/RESTAPI/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

What I need to do is be able to POST/GET to this API from another computer on the same network.  I can POST/GET/etc. on my own computer using the YARC Google Chrome extension.  If I am debugging the API from Visual Studio, the breakpoint hits letting me know that it's working, I also get the 200 response back.

[image]

I'd like to be able to POST/GET to this API from another computer that lives on the same network.  I always get a connection timeout error.  The URL seen in the YARC app photo uses http://172.16.1.132:100/RestAPI/api/RESTAPI where "172.16.1.132" is my PC's ethernet port ip address for the port I am connected to. ":100" is the port that I have bound in IIS, ":80" could also be used.  "RestAPI" is the name of the API that I am trying to call and "api/RESTAPI" is how to call the POST/GET method.

I've tried:
Completely disabling my firewall and Windows Defender;
Disabling the firewall on my router;
various configurations of the URL (different ports/authentication types/etc).

I'm very new to web apps and networking and I'm not even sure if what I am trying to do is possible.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You said you've tried it, but you haven't described what happens when you try it. Does it fail? What is the error? Be specific.

Comment: @mason The connection times out.  With a GET, I should receive a string with "value 1", "value 2" but I do not receive any response.  If I'm debugging the application, I should also hit a breakpoint but nothing happens. "The connection has timed out.  The server 172.16.1.132 is taking too long to respond"

Answer (score 0):

Use iisexpress-proxy - A simple local proxy for accessing IIS Express from remote machines.

Open command prompt as administrator and run

npm install -g iisexpress-proxy

then

iisexpress-proxy 100 to 81 (100 - localPort and 81 proxyPort)

Access the API using this address on the other PC http://172.16.1.132:81/RestAPI/api/RESTAPI

Note: instead of 81 any other unused port can also be taken.

Comment: I will try it on Monday. Thanks a lot for the reply. I’ll let you know if it works.

Comment: I got the proxy running but I am still unable to access the web service from another PC on the same network.  I tried switching Visual Studio to use IISExpress and forwarded the port to the proxy port 81 with no luck.  Do I have to configure the proxy on the PC I am trying to connect WITH?

Comment: Turned out there was a firewall running from a 3rd party VPN client.  I was not VPN'd in but their firewall was still running